# jquery method for a prototype method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to auto populate the drop down list box based on the selection from the previous drop down. I saw an example in the web and it uses replace_html in the controller. The rest of my application is based on the jquery.Could you please let me know how to achieve it with jquery.

My Controller code:

```
def  update_releases 
  puts "inside func"
  project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) 
  @releases = project.releases
  render :update do |page| 
    page.replace 'releases'
    page.replace_html 'cycles', :partial => 'cycles', :object => cycles
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write inline jquery code, like this:

```
def  update_releases 
  puts "inside func"
  project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) 
  @releases = project.releases
  render :update do |page|
    page << "$('#cycles').html(\"<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'cycles', :object => cycles ) %>\" );"
  end
end
```

better is to use js.erb files (given that you're using rails3):

```
def  update_releases 
  project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) 
  @releases = project.releases
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and create a **update_releases.js.erb** template:

```
$('#cycles').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'cycles', :object => @cycles ) %>" )
```

Comment: Hi Shm,Thanks a lot for the answwer. where the update_releases.js.erb file should be placed in the views directory or the controller's directory.

Comment: place it in the view directory. (same folder as the index.html.erb file for the controller)

Comment: Hi,Thanks a ton.It worked perfectly.I ahve been struggling to get this work for more than a week.Thanks a ton.If i get an oppurtunity to vote ur answer to infinity i would.